# $.Callbacks().disable() vs $.Callbacks().lock()

Tags: jquery

The jQuery documentation for both basically states the same thing so I was wondering if there's any major difference, if any, between the two. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation on this is actually really bad, so here's what I found by [studying the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/callbacks.js):

**[`lock`](http://api.jquery.com/callbacks.lock/) only prevents future [`fire`](http://api.jquery.com/callbacks.fire/) calls, but does not prevent functions to be [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/callbacks.add/)ed.**

---

Here's a quick rundown of the methods:

- [**`empty`**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/callbacks.js#L142-146) - Removes any callbacks registered thus far.
- [**`lock`**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/callbacks.js#L156-163) - Prevents further calls to `fire`, but allows more callbacks to be `add`ed.
- [**`disable`**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/callbacks.js#L147-151) - Prevents further calls to both `fire` & `add`.

---

To understand all this, let's start with an explanation of [the `memory` flag](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/#supported-flags):

If the callback object is constructed with the `memory` flag, it'll keep track of the last `fire` call, and any callback added later will immediately be called. Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/GyxwA/):

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks('memory');

callbacks.add(function(){
    console.log('first');
});

callbacks.fire();

callbacks.add(function(){
    console.log('second');
});
```

This'll also log ***second***, even though it was added after the `fire` call.

---

If you `disable` it though, it'll completely wipe the memory. Here's [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/GyxwA/3/):

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks('memory');

callbacks.add(function(){
    console.log('first');
});

callbacks.fire();
callbacks.disable();

callbacks.add(function(){
    console.log('second');
});

callbacks.fire();
```

This'll only log ***first***, since `callbacks` has been disabled before the second function was added.

---

However, if you use `lock` it instead, functions added later *will* be called. Here's [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/GyxwA/4/):

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks('memory');

callbacks.add(function(){
    console.log('first');
});

callbacks.fire();
callbacks.lock();

callbacks.add(function(){
    console.log('second');
});

callbacks.fire();
```

This'll also log ***second***, but only once; since the object was `lock`ed, any further calls to `fire` will be ignored.

Comment: Waittt... don't you need to put a name for the callbacks when you add it?

Comment: @Kpower - Nope. Only if you want to later be able to `remove` them.

Comment: @Kpower - `empty` only clear the callback list, it doesn't wipe the memory: http://jsfiddle.net/GyxwA/1/

Comment: ahhh ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kpower - Since the documentation is not very thorough on this, I suggest you [study the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/callbacks.js).

Comment: @JosephSilber -I have another question about the lock. here is the source code of lock:                             lock:function() {
       stack = undefined;
       if ( !memory || memory === true ) {
           self.disable();
       }
       return this;
},                                                                  What does "stack" property used for. in each case above, the stack property is "undefined", so when does stack has value?

Comment: @jason - It's used internally for the undocumented [`fireWith` method](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/callbacks.js#L171-#L182), which allows you to call the list of callbacks with a custom context (the value of `this` within the callbacks).

Comment: @JosephSilber - thanks for your reply. In the fireWith method, if(firing){stack.push(args)}, but when does firing is true? Since in the fire method, when all callbacks are invoked, the firing is set to false.

Comment: @jason - Exactly. You might be calling `fireWith` (or `fire`, which internally calls `fireWith`) from within one of your callbacks, in which case `firing` will be `true`.

Comment: @JosephSilber -Which scenario will call fire() within callback? What is the purpose? Could you give an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jason - Like I said, if you call `fire` from within one of your callbacks, the first pass will complete before the second pass starts. [Here's a demo illustrating that](http://plnkr.co/edit/I2rJ7F?p=preview). For comparison, [here's the same demo with a custom `Callbacks` implementation](http://plnkr.co/edit/5eHEHW?p=preview), which doesn't use `stack` (all I edited is the `fireWith` method). The difference is self-evident: the second pass interrupts the first pass, such that the remaining callbacks never fire with the arguments provided for the first pass.

Comment: @jason - BTW, [the `fireWith` method *is* documented](http://api.jquery.com/callbacks.fireWith/). Mea culpa.

Comment: @JosephSilber I really appreciate for your help:)

Comment: @jason - All I did was study the source code. Follow the logic to where it leads you...