# stop jquery animation on multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a function that triggers a series of animations when called.  I want to be able to stop all of the animations when a link is clicked.  The code is as follows:

```
var slogan = false;
function slogan_slide(){
    slogan = true;
    if($('#slogan').is(':visible')){
        $('#slogan_1').fadeIn(500);
        $('#slogan_2').delay(1300).fadeIn(500);
        $('#slogan_3').delay(2600).fadeIn(500);
        $('#slogan_4').delay(3900).fadeIn(500, function(){
            $('#slogan_1').delay(3000).hide();
            $('#slogan_2').delay(3000).hide();
            $('#slogan_3').delay(3000).hide();
            $('#slogan_4').delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function(){
                $('#home_content').fadeIn(500);
                slogan = false;
            });
         });
     }
}

function slogan_stop(){
    $('#slogan_1').stop(true).fadeOut(500);
    $('#slogan_2').stop(true).fadeOut(500);
    $('#slogan_3').stop(true).fadeOut(500);
    $('#slogan_4').stop(true).fadeOut(500);
    $('#home_content').stop(true).fadeOut(500); 
}

$(document).on('click','a', function(){
    if(slogan) slogan_stop();
});
```

This stops all the animations except the callback on #home_content to fadeIn.  How do I prevent that callback from happening?

Comment: Just a suggestion: Have you tried `.stop(true,true)` with both boolean values? I see your current .stop calls are only with a single boolean `.stop(true)`.  The second boolean tells jQuery to jump immediately to the end of the animation.  Not sure if this will help or not...

Comment: I didn't want to jump to the end of the fadeIns because of the onscreen effect everything suddenly appearing.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle of this...

Comment: Hmm you may want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252709/callbacks-disable-vs-callbacks-lock
You might be able to access the callback directly through one of those methods (such as the callback `empty` method).